# Fetching updates from different database and update source

Tags: java, database, spring, architecture, event-handling

In my application ***(app A)*** I have many trades. For each of these trades I need to fetch the clearing status from a second application ***(app B)*** database.

Currently, I have a **Spring Boot Java Application** with a Scheduled component that queries `app B` database every 10 minutes to check for all the **cleared** trades to then match with `app A` records and update accordingly if not already updated.

While I am querying app B database looking at only today's updates to minimize the dataset, it is expected to grow.

**What I would like to do?**

I would like to avoid retrieving the same set of records throughout the day every 10 minutes from `app B` database.

Is there a clean approach to solving this problem?

Instead of looking on **app A** for uncleared records and then going to **app B** database to query if trades cleared, I want to pick up the events in **app B** that are new and update accordingly in **app A**.

What would you suggest? Are there any tools I can use?

Comment: Can't your "events" (I assume records) have some creation timestamp and your app B mainain a "last lookup" date? Then you could get all records that are newer than that date.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the owner of the application that has the App B database would expose an API for you to retrieve these trades rather than having you connect to their database directly or they would publish them to a message queue for you to consume from. These are standard patterns that are used in trading environments.

Generally it isn't a good idea to integrate directly with another applications database and polling is usually used as an integration of last resort.